# store string inside machine without using Database

Tags: node.js

I have created NodeJS application that communicate with SerialPort for example `COM7`.

because the `COM` name is not static it could be change all the time.

I'm looking for a way to save `COM7` as a String inside a machine, and able to fetch it to NodeJS code. 
and also change it remotly.

It is the same idea like database, but I see it really unnecessary to start database for only 1 record.
Look like Session on php but permanent.

** OS: Raspbian.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not save it to disk, if you need it to be permanent? If that's ok, and you don't know how to do it, I'll post an example.

Comment: Thanks, but because hardware could change and user can unplug USB from ‘com7’ to ‘com5’ I need a way to change it remotely, and fetch it inside the code as string. If your example fit that’s gonna be great :)

Comment: So an http request to fetch that string would be ok?

Comment: Content need to store on device :)

Comment: Where does COM7 comes from? Do you check inside nodejs which SerialPort is connected? Post your code, and we will be able to help you a little more, not enough context.

Comment: why would you save to external usb drive and not to the microsd? last I checked you can't pull out the microsd on a raspberry with out consequences.

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande COM7 is a nick name for a usb port, the first step is to recognize the port(inside my api) and set it. because the port can always can change by user its could be change to COM8 and the code suddenly stop work(client surprise). 
https://pastebin.com/hRXw1fQ8

Comment: @Darkrum the code stored inside server no manually access.

Comment: @itzikb what are you on about? I don't even think you know.